# Google App Engine Channel API pricing: $0.01 or $0.001 for 100 channels?

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I found two different prices for [Google's Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview).

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing says:

> Channel opened $0.00001 ($0.001/100 channels)

https://cloud.google.com/pricing/ says:

> $0.01 / 100 channels opened

Are those sites referring to different operations? Or is one source outdated? Assuming I want to use the Channel API in a server application used by 1M users (=1M channels) per day, will it cost

**$0.01 / 100 * 1,000,000 = $100**

or

**$0.001 / 100 * 1,000,000 = $10**

per day? Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: Good find. Think this belongs on superuser

Answer (score 2):

In the admin console billing page it's showing $0.01/100, I'm assuming that's the one that counts.

Comment: Sounds like everybody agrees that there is a typo on https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing. I used the feedback link on the site yesterday to report the potential error. In the meantime, it would great if Google could confirm that the price really is $0.01 for 100 channels.

Comment: Thanks for reporting! We'll fix this ASAP.